# Почему не работает цикл и условие?

Tags: python, циклы

```
choice = ""
while choice != "Да" or "Нет":
    choice = input("Могу предложить подсказку(введите Да или Нет): ")
    if choice == "Да":
        points = 5
```

Проблема в том что цикл бесконечен. Не очень понимаю, почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Условие вашего цикла эквивалентно `(choice != "Да") or "Нет"`. Это условие всегда истинно (если условие в скобках ложно, то "Нет" интерпретируется как истина, т.к. это непустая строка), поэтому цикл бесконечный.

Вам нужно условие `choice != "Да" and choice != "Нет"` или `choice not in {"Да", "Нет"}`.

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду круглые скобки `choice not in ("Да", "Нет")` (tuple) или на худой конец квадратные (list)?

Comment: @VisionN, я имел в виду set, и это фигурные скобки.

Comment: А, это новый синтаксис из 2.7/3. Не знал :)

Answer (score -1):

Во-первых, не правильно написано условие цикла. И не понятно: если choice равен "Нет", то что?

```
choice = ""

while choice != "Да" or choice != "Нет":
    choice = input("Могу предложить подсказку(введите Да или Нет): ")

    if choice == "Да":
        print("points = 5")
        points = 5
    elif choice == "Нет":
        print("Выходим из цикла, не взяв подсказку!")
```