# Почему зацикливание?

Tags: python

Путь к каталогу: C:/
Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): 5
Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): 1
Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): 1
Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): 1
Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): 1

```
import os

#ИНТЕРФЕЙС
dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')
while not os.path.isdir(dirpath): #проверка пути
    print('Такого каталога нет')
    dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')

option =  input('Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): ')


if option == '1':
    pattern = input('Шаблон имени файла: ')
    func_name(dirpath, name)
if option == '2':
    pattern = input('Шаблон имени файла: ')
    func_pattern(dirpath, pattern)
if option == '3':
    moreless = input('Меньше или больше определенного размера (<-меньше,>-больше): ')
    size = int(input('Размер (в Кб): '))
    func_size(dirpath, moreless, size)
if option == '4':
    word = input('Введите слово которое есть в искаемом файле: ')
    func_word(dirpath, word)
while not option == '1' or '2' or '3' or '4':
    option =  input('Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): ')
```

Comment: Версия питона какая?

Comment: К модераторам: отзываю свой голос за закрытие, т.к. ответ первоначально указанный мной по ссылке не является полным ответом на данный вопрос. Ответ данный @Avernial более полный.

Comment: @nicolia, в дополнению к ответу Avernial, ознакомьтесь, почему не работает ваше условие в последнем цикле: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414670/1365

Answer (score 2):

У вас ошибка в логике работы. А конкретно в последнем условии. Сделайте вот так.

```
import os

# ИНТЕРФЕЙС
dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')
while not os.path.isdir(dirpath):  # проверка пути
    print('Такого каталога нет')
    dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')

option = None

while not option in ['1', '2', '3', '4']:
    option = input('Параметр поиска (1-имя,2-шаблон,3-размер,4-по содержимому): ')
else:
    if option == '1':
        pattern = input('Шаблон имени файла: ')
        func_name(dirpath, name)
    if option == '2':
        pattern = input('Шаблон имени файла: ')
        func_pattern(dirpath, pattern)
    if option == '3':
        moreless = input('Меньше или больше определенного размера (<-меньше,>-больше): ')
        size = int(input('Размер (в Кб): '))
        func_size(dirpath, moreless, size)
    if option == '4':
        word = input('Введите слово которое есть в искаемом файле: ')
        func_word(dirpath, word)
```